# Non-English Character Problem When Updating Migration in .NET 6 EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, connection-string, webapi, non-english

I am trying to make a CRUD with a .NET 6 Web API & Entity Framework Core and I'm having a problem doing a migration update. MS SQL is used as database.

The name of the database given to me is made with a non-English naming like '`ZİRVEDB`'. I don't know why they did such a thing, but they named the database like this.

The "ConnectionStrings" in the appsettings.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection" : "Server=myServerAddress;Database=ZİRVEDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Program.cs file contains:

```
global using MyAPI.Data;
global using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And when I try to "`dotnet ef database update`", due to non-English character, it creates a new database like Z�RVEDB and saves the migration there. But I already have an existing database and I want it to save in that database.

Here's what I've tried:

1. `"...;Database=\"ZİRVEDB\""`
2. `"..;Database='ZİRVEDB'"`
3. Set it to "`Turkish_CI_AI`" in database settings.

But these did not work. How can i solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Suggest you report a bug in the EF Core github repository

Comment: I would like to confirm with you whether you use Turkish only in DB name or your DB also contains values in Turkish language? If only DB name has Turkish character then you could replace `ZİRVEDB` with `ZIRVEDB` may help to quick fix this issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Only database name contains Turkish character. There is no such situation in the tables in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Startup cs

services.AddWebEncoders(o => {
o.TextEncoderSettings = new System.Text.Encodings.Web.TextEncoderSettings(UnicodeRanges.All);
});

bunu yaparsan düzelir

Comment: var result = string.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
return Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(result));
veya bunuda yapabilirsin...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).